# Responsive Design Jquery Navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I am controlling the mobile menu I've created with Jquery. When it loads I need it to be hidden, revealing itself only when the user clicks on the 'header', activating the command I've created. I also need the menu to STAY open when the user scrolls down the page. The option outlined in this post almost works.

Right now when the page loads the menu is open. If I specify it to be closed using else $nav.hide();}, when I load it on my mobile device and try scrolling down the menu will close automatically. If I specify that it remain hidden upon loading with media queries, I have problems in the desktop layout (when i resize it, the menu links do not return to their original position, instead of being side by side they stack under each other-I am using inline-block as my display since it works better with my layout than floating the elements.)

If anyone has any ideas or can point me in the right direction, it'd be very much appreciated. Thank you.

JQUERY

```
var screensize = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

$(function (){

var $window = $(window),
    $nav = $('.link'),
    $button = $('header');

$button.on('click', function (){
    $nav.slideToggle(500);
});  

$window.on('resize', function (){
    if ($window.width() > 600)
    { $nav.show();  
    } 
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found my problem was being created via scrolling error on the iphone5. I have tested it on other mobile devices and it works perfectly. I have modified the code to thanks to help from another user. I have kept the answer Jquery specific so I haven't modified any CSS.

```
var screensize = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

$(document).ready(function(){

var $window = $(window),
    $nav = $('.link'),
    $button = $('header');

$button.on('click', function (){
    $nav.slideToggle(400);
});  

function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width > 600) {
        $nav.show();
    } else {
       $nav.hide();
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
});
});
});
```